# How to retrieve pages filtered by a tag from OneNote API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

Some of my pages have a OneNote Tag in it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-note-tags

I would like to retrieve only pages that contain a specific tag from a notebook.

Currently, I would need to

1. Get all the sections from a notebook
2. Get all the pages from a section
3. Get all content from pages
4. check if it contains data-tag="important" (example)

Is there a better way of doing this via the ms graph? (possibly via a combination of expand/filter)

Best

Comment: To get all the pages in a notebook use the call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages` and to compare the data-tag="important" is present in the content or not, it is not possible as of now but if your data is small you can use a work arround by calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/pageid/content` and compare it for each page. If you have tons of data, it would be better to raise a Uservoice for this scenario by going to the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359605)

Comment: Moving this to Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the pages in a notebook use the HTTP call below.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages
```

To compare the `data-tag="important"` is present in the content or not, it is not possible as of now but if your data is small you can use a work around by calling the below HTTP call and compare it for each page on your end.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/pageid/content
```

If you have tons of data, it would be better to raise a Uservoice for this scenario by going to the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359605) so that it can be implemented in the future.